# Create by adding columns for labeled data in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, label

supposed my dataframe

```
df1
name startdate    label
A    14-05-07     1
A    14-05-21     2
A    14-06-01     3
A    14-06-15     4
B    18-10-05     1
B    18-10-19     2
B    18-10-31     3
C    19-03-04     1     
C    19-03-17     2
C    19-03-31     3
D    16-04-01     1
D    16-04-21     2
..
```

```
df2
name date     
A    14-04-05
A    14-05-08
A    15-01-05
B    18-07-05
B    18-10-02
C    19-01-03
C    19-03-30
D    16-04-01
..
```

There are two data frames df1 and df2 have the same common key 'name'

I want to add the 'startdate' labeled df1 to the column of df2.

**output what I want**

```
name date     label1   label2   label3   label4   ..
A    14-04-05 14-05-07 14-05-21 14-06-01 14-06-15
A    14-05-08 14-05-07 14-05-21 14-06-01 14-06-15
A    15-01-05 14-05-07 14-05-21 14-06-01 14-06-15
B    18-07-05 18-10-05 18-10-19 18-10-31 nan
B    18-10-02 18-10-05 18-10-19 18-10-31 nan
C    19-01-03 19-03-04 19-03-17 19-03-31 nan
C    19-03-30 19-03-04 19-03-17 19-03-31 nan
D    16-04-01 16-04-01 16-04-21 nan      nan
```

Is there way?
thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = df2.join(df1.pivot('name','label','startdate').add_prefix('label'), on='name')
print (df)
  name      date    label1    label2    label3    label4
0    A  14-04-05  14-05-07  14-05-21  14-06-01  14-06-15
1    A  14-05-08  14-05-07  14-05-21  14-06-01  14-06-15
2    A  15-01-05  14-05-07  14-05-21  14-06-01  14-06-15
3    B  18-07-05  18-10-05  18-10-19  18-10-31       NaN
4    B  18-10-02  18-10-05  18-10-19  18-10-31       NaN
5    C  19-01-03  19-03-04  19-03-17  19-03-31       NaN
6    C  19-03-30  19-03-04  19-03-17  19-03-31       NaN
7    D  16-04-01  16-04-01  16-04-21       NaN       NaN
```